# iOS Universal Linking with Browsers other than Safari

Tags: ios, swift, safari, deep-linking, ios14

I have successfully implemented iOS universal linking, which serves as a vital feature for opening our app from marketing emails. These emails often contain HTML content, and when a user clicks on a specific href tag, our app should ideally open if it is installed on their device. However, with the latest iOS versions, users have the option to change their default browsers. Consequently, when a user selects a browser other than Safari as their default, the clicked URL opens in that default browser, and our application fails to open.

After conducting some research, I discovered that universal links only work with Safari redirection. Hence, my questions are as follows:

1. Is there any alternative method to achieve deeplinking when a user selects a default browser other than Safari?
2. Is there a way to forcefully open an href URL in Safari only on iOS, using any HTML/Javascript tags?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions regarding this matter.

Comment: When faced with this problem recently, we created a web page at the universal link location that displayed an 'open in app' button.  The link behind the button was our app url (appname://).  We suffixed this with the path to the web page so that when that url launched our app we could still route to the correct place.